# Output from sys.exit sometimes appears on terminal before output from print

Tags: python, terminal

Running this code multiple times, I sometimes get the expected output but otherwise I get the "End of list" caused by `StopIteration` *first*, and then the prints from the loop.

```
import sys

data = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def myf(*args):
    for arg in args:
        yield arg

generator_object = myf(*data)

while True:
    try:
        print(next(generator_object))
    except StopIteration:
        sys.exit('End of list')
```

The output I would expect every time is the one with "End of list" last, since the exception should be raised *after* the generator has run out of items to print. However, maybe half the time, I get this:

```
End of list
a
b
c

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Running this code multiple times looks like this:

[GIF showing multiple executions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5edlD.gif)

Why?

Comment: You mean, that the string `End of list` is printed before `a b c` is not what you are expecting? `GIF showing multiple executions` ? Couldn't you like copy text and paste it?

Comment: I suppose it may be dependent on the environment you use to run your code? What if you run it right in the console? $ python script.py ?

Comment: Thanks Maxim, I tried the IDLE now and the error (?) does not occur there after a few attempts. Before I worked in PyCharm. Any explanation though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string given to *sys.exit()* is written to stderr whereas *print()* goes (by default) to stdout. Although the output is ultimately to a terminal, the order isn't guaranteed due to independent buffering of the two streams.

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/sys.html#module-sys)

Comment: Cool, thanks. I wasn't aware of those streams.
Adding time.sleep(0.1) before sys.exit() keeps the order.

Comment: Ordering is guaranteed to be preserved _if and only if_ both streams are copies of the same file descriptor. Sometimes that's true, as when at a terminal and nobody has done anything funny. (stderr is unbuffered by default and stdout is line-buffered by default when output is to a terminal, which means that for most use cases, when writing output direct to a user they're both promptly flushed; when output isn't going to a file, socket or other non-TTY destination, then, concern is less buffering and more the fact that UNIX only guarantees serialization in the two-copies-of-the-same-FD case).